# What to show as proof of accommodation when applying for a UK visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-accommodation

I am applying for UK Visa and for the accommodation I have confirmed the reservation of a hotel through bookings.com. I also received an email regarding the same, under PAY AT THE HOTEL option.

I would like to know if this is enough for the visa application or do I have to make the payment and show the receipt?

Comment: @jcaron this question can be answered generally without all that information. Nandana, have you read the guidance? What did it say?

Answer (score 3):

You should not submit a hotel booking with your application.

> Section 4: documents you should not send unless 
>   specifically requested
>
> This page provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to consider your application.
>
> - if you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide multiple copies of the same documents
> - bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of 
>     application
> - driving licence
> - photographs (other than passport photographs required in section 1)
> - notarial certificates
> - business cards
> - **hotel bookings**
> - flight bookings
> - photocopies of bank cards
> - credit card statements
> - certificates relating to leisure activities
> - evidence of car ownership
> - travel insurance
> - sponsor’s utility bills
> - sponsor’s council tax bills
> - educational certificates (unless specifically listed in section 3)

Emphasis added.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents

Since you should not send a hotel booking, you certainly should not send evidence that you've already paid for your room.  You are advised against paying, or making a nonrefundable reservation, because of the possibility that your visa application will be refused.

Comment: +1, bookmarked so future questions can be hammered in favour of this answer, thanks